# Satechi Multiport disrupts LAN

Tags: networking, troubleshooting, wired-networking, docking-station

We have a wired LAN network with about 100 pcs, connected via various unmanaged switches. Every now and then, all devices on one specific switch lose connection. After some searching, I found that as soon as I disconnected one specific cable from the switch, **instantly** all connectivity will be restored.  For example, a browser that is trying to load a page (but nothing was showing up) will immediately display the website as soon as I disconnect this specific cable.

Following the cable, I found that it connects to a Satechi Multiport docking station. As long as the docking station is connected to a laptop, the network works fine. The docking station has a power connector, that can be used to power the laptop that is connected to it. I discovered that when the docking station is connected to power, but not to the laptop, it will disrupt the LAN network it is connected to. If the power is **not** connected or the laptop **is** connected, everything works fine.

The owner of the docking station prefers to leave the power to the docking station connected, because then he only needs to plug in one connector into his laptop, instead of having to connect the power separately. This means that every now and then he will leave the docking station connected to power and ethernet while disconnecting his laptop, and 10 people lose internet access.

It almost seems that, when the docking station is causing trouble, all network packets on this switch will go to it. As soon as the docking station becomes unavailable (i.e. gets disconnected), the switch 'realises' that the packets will actually have to go somewhere else and sends them to the correct machine.

What could be causing this?